# Prevent duplicate calls to action on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have following actionlink on my view which calls an action on controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send Request", "SendRequest", new { id = item.CertificateId })
```

Following URL is formed once link is clicked.

```
http://localhost:61742/Controller/SendRequest/17
```

Now when I hit refresh same action is called again which inserts a a duplicate row to my table. Is there a way to prevent duplicate calls to my action or should I add a check before inserting a row to my table.

I even tried changing my view to call HttpPost Action but that also gets called on refresh again.

Comment: It cannot get called by itself unless you are having it triggered on page load. If you change that you'll be good.

Comment: Well, you should search for  "PRG pattern".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the page you are refreshing is your Do Action (SendRequest) page.

I would suggest that your Action returns a redirect back to your original page OR to a "thanks for submitting" page.

You can do this in your SendRequest action (which you should keep as `HttpPost`), for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendRequest(int id)
{
    //Do you Send Request logic here

    //Redirect the user to another page once complete
    return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
}
```

which will take the user to a URL like: `http://localhost:61742/Controller/Thanks/`

Of course, the user could still then press the browser "back" button to return to the SendRequest URL, so I would advise putting in as much server side validation as you can to prevent duplicate entries. Other than that though, there isn't much you can do about a user choosing to click the "Send Request" link multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, RedirectToAction Works.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you're decorating your Action with `[HttpPost]`, the browser should at least alert the user before 'refreshing' (re-posting the data).

Usually, redirection is the the simplest solution to the problem. for example:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SendRequest(int id)
 {
     ....

     return Redirect("some_url");
 }
```